# Plot only OOB Error from RandomForest

Tags: r, data-visualization, random-forest

I am using random Forest in R and only want to Plot the `OOB Error`.

When I do `plot(myModel, log = "y")` I get a diagram where each of my class is a line. On the `x-axis` are the `ntree` while on the `x-Axis` there is the Error rate.

[image]

When I try `plot(myModel$err.rate, log = "y")` I get this:

[image]

Why is there no line like the ones above?

Answer (score 0):

The `err.rate` is stored in a matrix where the first column is the `OOB Error`. Each class gets its own column.

To access the `err.rate` do this `myModel $err.rate[,1]`, for plotting simply `plot(myModel $err.rate[,1])`.